Bond Font Size and Image with Thresholds
I'd like to make my application resizable. I want to resize all child elements and its font size and images depending on the height and width. But I do not want that font size and image fall under or exceed a certain value.
I followed the instructions on the following page: Bind Font Size in JavaFX?
I am attaching a cut of my code:
FXFontBindApp.java:
package how.to.resize.in.java.fx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXFontBindApp extends Application {
    private DoubleProperty fontSize = new SimpleDoubleProperty(10);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FontResizeExample.fxml"));
        StackPane pane = fxmlLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Font Resize Example");
        fontSize.bind(scene.widthProperty().add(scene.heightProperty()).divide(50));
        pane.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: ", fontSize.asString()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}


FXFontBindController.java:
package how.to.resize.in.java.fx;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class FXFontBindController implements Initializable {
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }
}

FontResizeExample.fxml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import java.lang.String?>
<StackPane fx:id="stackPane" stylesheets="@root.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="how.to.resize.in.java.fx.FXFontBindController">
    <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane">
        <VBox fx:id="outerVBox" spacing="10.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
            <VBox fx:id="header" alignment="TOP_CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                <Label fx:id="headerTitle" styleClass="title" text="Please enter username and password"/>
            </VBox>
            <VBox fx:id="enterRootPasswords" alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                <VBox fx:id="rootPasswordFields" spacing="5.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <PasswordField fx:id="pin1" promptText="Pin" />
                    <HBox VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                        <Region HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                        <Hyperlink fx:id="forgotPassword" alignment="CENTER" text="Forgot Password?" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                    </HBox>
                </VBox>
            </VBox>
            <VBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <Label fx:id="selectCardReaderLabel" text="Select Smart Card Reader" />
                    <ComboBox fx:id="selectCardReaderCombo" promptText="Select Smart Card Reader">
                        <items>
                            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                                <String fx:value="Three"/>
                                <String fx:value="Two"/>
                                <String fx:value="One"/>
                            </FXCollections>
                        </items>
                    </ComboBox>
                </VBox>
            </VBox>
            <VBox fx:id="footer" alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                <HBox fx:id="hBoxOkCancel" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <Region HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                    <Button fx:id="btnLogin" graphicTextGap="10.0" text="OK" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                        <graphic>
                            <ImageView fitHeight="16.0" fitWidth="16.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                <Image url="@hook.png" />
                            </ImageView>
                        </graphic>
                    </Button>
                </HBox>
            </VBox>
            <padding>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
            </padding>
        </VBox>
    </AnchorPane>
</StackPane>

root.css:
.label {
    -fx-font-size: 0.9375em;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Black";
}
.title{
    -fx-font-size: 1.25em;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Black";
}
.password-field {
    -fx-font-size: 0.9375em;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Black";
}
.hyperlink {
    -fx-font-size: 0.75em;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Black";
    -fx-text-fill: #005f6a;
}
.button {
    -fx-background-color: green;
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Black";
    -fx-font-size: 1em;
    -fx-cursor: hand;
}
.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: darkgreen;
}
.combo-box-base {
    -fx-background-color: green;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-font-size: 0.875em;
}
.combo-box-base:hover {
    -fx-background-color: darkgreen;
}
.combo-box .list-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-size: 0.875em;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial Black";
}
.combo-box-base .arrow-button .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.combo-box-base:showing {
    -fx-background-color: darkgreen;
}
.combo-box-base:showing:hover {
    -fx-background-color: darkgreen;
}
.combo-box .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
.combo-box .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:hover,
.combo-box .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: darkgreen;
}

Furthermore, the two lines, see below, change the font size slightly. How can I fix this additionally?
        fontSize.bind(scene.widthProperty().add(scene.heightProperty()).divide(50));
        pane.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: ", fontSize.asString()));



It seems like the wrong approach.  Changing the font size inside a Button, for instance, won't necessarily change the size of the Button.  It'll just have goofy small (or big) text inside it.  What you could do is simply scale the root element of your window using scaleX, and scaleY.   Then everything would shrink or grow.

@DaveB binding the font size of the root pane as is done in this example may work better than you might expect because all of the in-built JavaFX controls will resize based on the inherited font size (including stuff like the button padding around text, checkboxes, up/down arrows in scroll bars, scroll bar widths, etc).  See How can I change the BASE font size in JavaFX 8 Modena theme.

That said, I don't know that all of the additional font size adjustments from the CSS file from the question will have the desired effects (goofy sized text may still appear :-), but they are minor size changes based on em values, so will probably be OK.

Related question and answer
If adopting the letterboxing scaling solution from this question, also see the related question and answer:

Resizing ComboBox by scaling screen size

Direct answer using font size binding
You can bind the font size to the max of the calculated size and your desired minimum size. That way the size will never go below your minimum.
fontSize.bind(
        Bindings.max(
                scene.widthProperty().add(
                        scene.heightProperty()
                ).divide(50),
                MIN_FONT_SIZE
        )
);

FontSizingApp.java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FontSizingApp extends Application {
    private static final double MIN_FONT_SIZE = 12;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // load the content
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
                FontSizingApp.class.getResource(
                        "fontResizeSample.fxml"
                )
        );
        Scene scene = new Scene(
                fxmlLoader.load()
        );

        // adjust the font size of the scene root to scale the scene content based on scene size.
        DoubleProperty fontSize = new SimpleDoubleProperty(MIN_FONT_SIZE);
        fontSize.bind(
                Bindings.max(
                        scene.widthProperty().add(
                                scene.heightProperty()
                        ).divide(50),
                        MIN_FONT_SIZE
                )
        );

        scene.getRoot().styleProperty().bind(
                Bindings.concat(
                        "-fx-font-size: ",
                        fontSize.asString()
                )
        );

        // show the stage.
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Font Sizing Example");
        stage.show();
    }
}

The rest of this answer uses a different approach, but the font size solution may still be a valid approach for you.
Alternate answer using scaling
An example based on DaveB's suggestion in comments to:

scale the root element of your window using scaleX, and scaleY

Uses an update of a solution from an old question:

JavaFX fullscreen - resizing elements based upon screen size

The concept behind the solution (letterboxing a UI resized using scale transforms) is provided in the above answer so I won't repeat it here.
Notes on UI scaling
There are advantages and disadvantages to both various UI scaling approaches, those are also discussed in some other answers I have provided on this site regarding interface scaling.
The standard method will be to use neither font size-based scaling nor scaling-based scaling, but instead to use layout panes to adjust the interface as described in the original Oracle tutorial on JavaFX layouts.
Scaling is usually best reserved for situations where one of the following applies:

The distance of the UI from the viewer may change (e.g. a television is often further away than a laptop screen, so a TV UI may scale everything larger).
The UI is larger for accessibility reasons (some people require larger UIs due to poorer eyesight).
The UI is a viewport into a large and detailed thing (e.g. scaling a map in and out).
Game-type UIs that don't use a lot of UI widgets and text.

However, for windowed UIs, often it is best to keep the UI elements at the same scale.  If the window is resized, adjust the UI to show more or less content rather than scaling a fixed amount of content up.  And if the size changes radically (e.g. from a laptop screen size to a phone screen size), then a different UI design completely is often preferred.
On scaling images
Bitmapped formats like images don't scale up that well.  If you want them to look good when enlarged, you need high-resolution images.  An alternative is to use a vector-based image format (e.g. SVG).  JavaFX 23 doesn't natively support the full SVG images except through the WebView control.  However, regions in JavaFX can have an SVG path shape applied to them (this is how modena.css creates scalable UI widgets such as checkmarks in checkboxes).  Additionally, you can directly draw SVGPath shapes in JavaFX.
Sample solution screenshots
These screenshots are based on the letterboxing solution, not the font size solution.
UI at the default size (also configured as the minimum size).

UI displayed full screen.

Example code
LetterBoxingApp.java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LetterBoxingApp extends Application {
    // a MIN_SCALE >= 1 will ensure that the scene content is never sized below its initial size.
    private static final double MIN_SCALE = 1;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // load the content
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
                LetterBoxingApp.class.getResource(
                        "letterboxingSample.fxml"
                )
        );
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();

        // create a letterboxed scene.
        LetterBoxer letterBoxer = new LetterBoxer();
        Scene scene = letterBoxer.box(
                root,
                MIN_SCALE
        );

        // show the stage.
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Letterboxing Example");
        stage.show();

        // optional code to set the minimum stage size to the preferred size.
        stage.setMinWidth(stage.getWidth());
        stage.setMinHeight(stage.getHeight());
    }
}

LetterBoxer.java
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;

public class LetterBoxer {
    public Scene box(final Parent content) {
        return box(content, 1);
    }

    public Scene box(final Parent content, final double minScale) {
        // the content is wrapped in a Group so that the stack centers
        // the scaled node rather than the untransformed node.
        Group group = new Group(content);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group);

        // generate a layout pass.
        group.applyCss();
        group.layout();

        // determine the default ratio of laid out components.
        final Bounds layoutBounds = group.getLayoutBounds();
        final double initWidth = layoutBounds.getWidth();
        final double initHeight = layoutBounds.getHeight();
        final double ratio = initWidth / initHeight;

        // place the root in a stack to keep it centered.
        scene.setRoot(
                new StackPane(
                        group
                )
        );

        // configure a listener to adjust the size of the scene content (by scaling it).
        BoxParams boxParams = new BoxParams(
                scene, minScale, ratio, initHeight, initWidth, content
        );

        // adjust the size of the scene content (by scaling it) if the size changes.
        BoxSizeAdjuster boxSizeAdjuster = new BoxSizeAdjuster(boxParams);
        scene.widthProperty().addListener(boxSizeAdjuster);
        scene.heightProperty().addListener(boxSizeAdjuster);

        return scene;
    }

    private record BoxParams(
            Scene scene,
            double minScale,
            double ratio,
            double initHeight, double initWidth,
            Parent content
    ) { }

    private static class BoxSizeAdjuster
            implements ChangeListener<Number> {

        private final BoxParams boxParams;
        private final Scale scale = new Scale();

        public BoxSizeAdjuster(BoxParams boxParams) {
            this.boxParams = boxParams;

            scale.setPivotX(0);
            scale.setPivotY(0);

            boxParams.content.getTransforms().setAll(scale);
        }

        @Override
        public void changed(
                ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue,
                Number oldValue,
                Number newValue
        ) {
            final double newWidth = boxParams.scene.getWidth();
            final double newHeight = boxParams.scene.getHeight();

            final double scaleFactor =
                    Math.max(
                            newWidth / newHeight > boxParams.ratio
                                    ? newHeight / boxParams.initHeight
                                    : newWidth / boxParams.initWidth,
                            boxParams.minScale
                    );

            scale.setX(scaleFactor);
            scale.setY(scaleFactor);
        }
    }
}

letterBoxingSample.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane stylesheets="@root.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/22" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <VBox fx:id="outerVBox" spacing="10.0">
         <VBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" spacing="5.0">
            <children>
                  <PasswordField fx:id="pin1" promptText="Pin" />
                   <Hyperlink fx:id="forgotPassword" alignment="CENTER" text="Forgot Password?" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" />
            </children>
         </VBox>
           <VBox alignment="CENTER">
               <Label fx:id="selectCardReaderLabel" text="Select Smart Card Reader" />
               <ComboBox fx:id="selectCardReaderCombo" promptText="Select Smart Card Reader">
                   <items>
                       <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                           <String fx:value="Three" />
                           <String fx:value="Two" />
                           <String fx:value="One" />
                       </FXCollections>
                   </items>
               </ComboBox>
           </VBox>
          <padding>
              <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
          </padding>
      </VBox>
   </center>
   <top>
        <Label fx:id="headerTitle" styleClass="title" text="Please enter username and password" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
   <bottom>
         <Button fx:id="btnLogin" graphicTextGap="10.0" text="OK" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
             <graphic>
                 <ImageView fitHeight="16.0" fitWidth="16.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <Image url="@hook.png" />
                 </ImageView>
             </graphic>
         </Button>
   </bottom>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</BorderPane>

hook.png
The checkbox image from the question.
root.css
The example CSS from the question.

Thanks for your help. I still have a question to your second approach. The second code works fine but it is missing resizing font sizes of the ComboBox elements. Can this be fixed?

@Billie Oh, I see, I hadn't tried opening the combo box from the scaled UI.  The combo box drop-down is displayed in a different window from the rest of the UI, so the scaling transforms in the solution don't automatically apply to it.  This answer is already very long.  Please ask your additional question as a new question.  Likely it would take some effort and time for somebody to solve that issue and the solution might not be trivial.

I created a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79250960/javafx-resizing-combobox-by-scaling-screen-size. Is it okay like that?

@Billie yep, looks like Sai solved it.  Asking new questions in questions means more people can answer :-)
