Resizing ComboBox by scaling screen size
I'd like to make my application resizable. I want to resize all child elements and its font size and images depending on the height and width.
I followed the instructions on the following page: Bond Font Size and Image with Thresholds. The answer contains two approaches. The first approach works fine but the second approach does not resize the ComboBox elements. What do I need to change to make the second approach work for dropdown of ComboBoxes as well?
Example code is given here Bond Font Size and Image with Thresholds as well.

Try to access the scale attribute from LetterBoxer and set that scale to listView of the ComboBox while showing.
selectCardReaderCombo.setOnShowing(e->{
    selectCardReaderCombo.getChildrenUnmodifiable().stream()
            .filter(n-> n.getStyleClass().contains("list-view"))
            .forEach(n->{
                n.getTransforms().setAll(boxSizeAdjuster.scale);
    });
});



I struggle with the following scenario: I start the application and select a card reader. If I now resize the window, the font size of the comboBox items are not adjusting with the new scale factor. I tested that scenario by addind to the class LetterBoxer (method 'box(final Parent node, final double minScale)') the following code: ComboBox selectCardReaderCombo = (ComboBox) scene.lookup("#selectCardReaderCombo"); selectCardReaderCombo.setOnShowing(e->{....

I am not sure what your code is. In my example if I use lookup.. it still works for me. Provide a minimal example of what you are tyring..

Yeah, you are right. Sorry! I still had the initial code, jewelsea changed the code later...Thank you very much for your help!
